# Filter mysql group by negative having contains

Tags: mysql, group-by

How can I get all of the values from 1 column, which do not (or do) have a specific value in one of their rows?

For instance, consider example table:

```
| ColA | ColB |
---------------
| aaa1 | zzz1 |
| aaa1 | zzz2 |
| aaa1 | zzz1 |
| aaa2 | zzz3 |
...
```

I want to get each of the values from ColA, where the set `group by ColA` does not contain a row with a specific value in ColB. i.e.

```
select ColA from test group by ColA not containing ColB like 'zzz2'
```

Unfortunately, as far as I know there isn't a `containing` keyword in MySQL. So what can I do instead? Is there some way to tell `having` to filter by another column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an anti-semijoin. Can be written with `NOT IN`, `LEFT JOIN / WHERE IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct ColA       -- if there is another table where ColA is unique
from test as a             -- use it here, instead of table test
                           -- and remove the distinct
where not exists
      ( select 1 
        from test as b
        where b.ColB = 'zzz2' 
          and b.ColA = a.ColA
      ) ;
```

You could also use `GROUP BY` with a `CASE` expression:

```
select ColA
from test
group by ColA
having count(case when ColB = 'zzz2' then 1 end) = 0 ;
```

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly. Is there a speed difference between the two versions?

Comment: Different execution plans, so different efficiency, depending on the distribution of data as well (i.e. if 95% of the `ColA` vlaues have a related `ColB='zzz2'` or if only 5% of them have)